# IOException caused by accessing a file that was still being moved

Tags: c#, .net

I have a solution that acts as an interface between two systems, reading files that were dropped on an FTP site and importing any orders/products/etc. into the target system.

When a file is picked up, it is moved to a temp file in the same location, and then the contents are read into an `XmlDocument`.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(pickupFolder, fileFilter, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach (string pathToFile in files)
{
  FileInfo srcFile = new FileInfo(pathToFile);
  string tmpFilename = Path.Combine(srcFile.DirectoryName, $"~{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(srcFile.Name)}.tmp");
  srcFile.MoveTo(tmpFilename);

  XmlDocument srcXml = new XmlDocument();
  try
  {
    using (FileStream fs = srcFile.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
      srcXml.Load(fs);
    }
  }
  catch (XmlException ex)
  {
    throw new FileException($"Invalid XML in {srcFile.Name}.", ex);
  }
}
```

Very, very occassionally, the interface will attempt to open the file so that it can be loaded into the `XmlDocument` while the moving process has not been completed, throwing an `IOException`. Is there some way to prevent this from happening?

What is the best way to create something like this that needs to iterate through and process files?

Comment: If you have no control over the timing, check for the exception and retry

Comment: I have no idea what this means: _"try to execute `MoveTo()` while the moving process has not been completed"_. How and why can the same file be moved twice? It sounds like a race condition that comes from multi threading. Are you using multiple threads for this process?

Comment: Also, when, from where and how often is this method called?

Comment: you can try move file by copying from source stream to destination manually and set destination stream as `write through`
this will skip any caching and write directly to disk. method execution will complete only after last byte was written

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry, corrected my question, I've not had my coffee yet this morning. I meant it tries to open the file and it raises an `IOException` because the file is in use, I think this is because `srcFile.MoveTo()` has not completed before the solution attempts to read the file.

Comment: @Saruman I had considered that, but not sure if it leaves enough time for the file to not be in use--difficult to test because it's a pretty rare occurrence. Maybe if I add a time delay to the catch to ensure it allows enough time?

Comment: `MoveTo(String destFileName)` calls the win32 api `MoveFile(FullPath, fullDestFileName))` it doesn't leave open file handles, something else like a virus checker or another thread or even another application probably has an open handle to it. your code you show is not the issue unless this is threaded. If that is the case (and its not a threading issue) the only thing (the the most appropriate thing you can do) is to expect this from time to time and give it a retry

Comment: FileInfo.MoveTo() is atomic at the file system level.  It is however not on a typical machine loaded with crapware, especially so for XML files.  The kind that checks for [this stuff](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_Security_Cheat_Sheet).  A retry loop may be necessary to fight back.

Comment: Maybe you don't want to retry immediately but simply handle that exception and skip this file. I dont know when you will run this import process next time, but often it's best to just log this and try again next time. You could store the problematic files in a `Dictionary<FileInfo, List<DateTime>>`. The key is the file and the value a list of all fail tries and their time. Then you have the count, and the time it was locked.

Answer (score 0):

The file move operation will throw an exception when the FTP server is still having a lock on the file. That may happen when the file is still being uploaded and is not yet completed, but is "visible" on the disk. Such collisions are rare, but they happen.

Start by checking your FTP server settings and features if it can hide incomplete files during upload. Another way is if you control the system that uploads files, you could upload them with a special "do not download" extension, and rename them after the upload is complete (atomic operation). Finally, as other pointed out, you could simply catch this specific exception and  retry with a delay.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, if process runs periodically, you can simply wrap it with try / catch block:

```
try
{
    srcFile.MoveTo(tmpFilename);
}
catch (Excption ex)
{
    // Write log entry if required
    continue;
}
```

If it's a one-off process, then you'll need to periodically attempt `MoveTo` until file is released and can be moved. Something like this may work:

```
int maxRetries = 60;
int retries = 0;
bool success = false;
while (retries < maxRetries)
{
    try
    {
        retries++;
        srcFile.MoveTo(tmpFilename);
        success = true;
        break;
    }
    catch (Excption ex)
    {
        // Log the error if required
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // Wait 1 second
    }
}
if (success == fale)
{
    // Log the error
    continue; // Skip the file if its still not released
}
```

The code tries to access the file every second during a minute. If it fails, then program skips this file and continues to next.